# ASP.NET ReturnURL to specific search results page

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I have an ASP.net site with C# backend code.  We have the following (abridged) code in it, which suits our needs, but it could be better.  This is on a page called SearchResults.aspx.  If the user is not logged in, the links will redirect them to the login page.  If they are logged in, it will redirect them to a lookup page for that item.  What I want it to do is to redirect them to the corresponding item page after they log in if they click the "not logged in link".  In what way would I need to supply the returnURL to the login page?  Every way I've tried, it just redirects me to the default page after login.

```
<AnonymousTemplate>
    <!--Want to change the link below so that the return URL will take me to 
    ItemInformation.aspx-->
     <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "itemnumber").ToString().Trim() %><br/>
     <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink1" NavigateUrl='Account/Login.aspx'>
     Please login to review information for this item.</asp:HyperLink>
</AnonymousTemplate>
<LoggedInTemplate>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#
       "~/ItemInformation.aspx?&ItemID=" + DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,
       "itemnumber").ToString().Trim() + "&itemdept=" + DataBinder.Eval(
       Container.DataItem, "department").ToString()%>'
       Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "itemnumber")%>'>
    </asp:HyperLink>
</LoggedInTemplate>
```

**Edit** - I'm using the default login structure for an ASP.net Web Application template, so this is all that is in the Login backend.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"];
        RegisterHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "Register.aspx?ReturnUrl=" +
          HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
    }
```

Comment: give us code where actual login is happening, ie - backend code for Login.aspx

Comment: I have included it, but I had used and ASP.net template which included the login page.  All that is in the backend is the load function above.

Comment: check first 3 lines of function you provided, what do you think it perform?

Comment: Sorry, that default redirect was added after for testing something else.  With the way that I was doing the redirectURL, it was still coming back to default without that code.  However, I don't think I was doing the returnURL properly because ItemInformation redirects to default if the querystring has a problem.

Comment: try following: 1. logout 2. enter search page 3. you're redirected to login, what is in url for this page?

Comment: I'm doing this on a test machine, so here's an example URL.  The way I had it, the Login link takes me to the Login page with url like this http://localhost:5629/Account/Login.aspx?returnURL=~/ItemInformation.aspx?&ItemID=123456&Dept=123.  I don't know if I'm supposed to be putting that '~/' in there but it remains in the Account directory if I don't.  I verified that I had removed the redirect to default, still coming back to default.

Comment: it is better to use just `/` instead of `~/`, but look solution from @Zerkey - it should work, at least it shows proper direction for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of my attempts to try to get it to work, I was only attempting to set the DestinationPageUrl attribute for my asp:Login control.  For some reason, it required me to use both this and the OnLoggedIn event together (I was not aware of this events existence before Zerkey pointed it out).  The Additional question mark in the return URL was also causing issues, so here's what I did in Login.aspx.

Markup:

```
<asp:Login ID="LoginUser" runat=server" EnableViewState="false"
       RenderOuterTable="false" OnLoggedIN="UserLoginOnLoggedIn">...</asp:Login>
```

Code:

```
protected void UserLoginOnLoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string itemid, itemdept;
        try
        {
            s1 = Request.QueryString["ItemID"].Trim();
            s2 = Request.QueryString["Dept"].Trim();
        }
        catch
        {
            //makes strings null if querystrings aren't present
            s1 = "";
            s2 = "";
        }
        string returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] + "&ItemID=" +
            Request.QueryString["ItemID"] + "&Dept=" +
                        Request.QueryString["Dept"];
        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s1) && 
        !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s2)))
            LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl = returnUrl;
        else
            LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl = "~/Default.aspx";
        Response.Redirect(LoginUser.DestinationPageUrl);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

On `SearchResults.aspx`

```
if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    Response.Redirect("/Login.aspx/?ReturnURL="+HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri); // dont forget to use urlencode
}
```

On `Login.aspx`

```
protected void Login_Click()
{
    if (Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"] != null)
    {
        Response.Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"]);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("/Home.aspx");
    }

}
```

Comment: OK, like a dummy I didn't even think about using the full paths instead of relative, so that does look more promising.  However, when I add the Login_Click event handler, it will cause it to not log in.  Doing it without still redirects to the home page.  The login page is using a validation group and asp: Login control, but I'm not seeing where the successful login page is set.

Comment: I personally don't use Login controls. `Login_Click()` was a placeholder method I named for readability. Looking into the Login control, the `LoggedIn` event is raised after the user is authenticated, so you would put your redirecting logic in that method.

Comment: Got it.  Needed that event...in one of my initial attempts I was trying to only rely on the DestinationPageUrl Attribute, which would work for other pages but not ones with additional querystring attributes.  Posted the solution.  Thanks for your help.